# Strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary install but strapi says module no

Tags: node.js, npm, strapi

I'm trying to switch from the AWS S3 upload provider to the cloudinary upload provider in Strapi. It worked great with the AWS S3 provider, but after install the cloudinary module the app will not start back up. Says the module is not found and to install strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary.

Cloudinary is in the package.json, it is in the node_modules folder.
Strapi 3.6.8 running in Docker with Postgres mount to a local volume /app:/srv/app
node 14.17 and npm 7

NPM list output excerpt

```
├─┬ strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary@3.6.8
```

│ ├─┬ cloudinary@1.26.3
│ │ ├── cloudinary-core@2.11.4
│ │ ├── core-js@3.6.5
│ │ ├── lodash@4.17.21 deduped
│ │ └── q@1.5.1

Package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
"knex": "0.21.18",
"pg": "8.5.1",
"strapi": "3.6.8",
"strapi-admin": "3.6.8",
"strapi-connector-bookshelf": "3.6.8",
"strapi-plugin-ckeditor5": "^1.13.0",
"strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.6.8",
"strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.6.8",
"strapi-plugin-documentation": "3.6.8",
"strapi-plugin-email": "3.6.8",
"strapi-plugin-i18n": "3.6.8",
"strapi-plugin-upload": "3.6.8",
"strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.6.8",
"strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary": "^3.6.8",
"strapi-utils": "3.6.8"
```

},

Output from Docker
Starting your app...

[2021-09-02T16:32:04.223Z] error Error: Cannot find module 'strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary'

Require stack:

- /srv/app/node_modules/strapi-plugin-upload/config/functions/bootstrap.js
- /srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/load/require-file-parse.js
- /srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/load/load-config-files.js
- /srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/core/load-apis.js
- /srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/core/load-modules.js
- /srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js
- /srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/index.js
- /srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/commands/develop.js
- /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/strapi/bin/strapi.js

  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)

  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)

  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)

  at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)

  at createProvider (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi-plugin-upload/config/functions/bootstrap.js:41:30)

  at module.exports (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi-plugin-upload/config/functions/bootstrap.js:13:36)

  at execLifecycle (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:437:14)

  at /srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:447:16

  at Array.map ()

  at Strapi.runLifecyclesFunctions (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:444:33)

  at Strapi.load (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:379:16)

  at async Strapi.start (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:196:9)

[2021-09-02T16:32:04.229Z] error bootstrap function in plugin "upload" failed

[2021-09-02T16:32:04.230Z] error Error: The provider package isn't installed. Please run `npm install strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary`

```
at createProvider (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi-plugin-upload/config/functions/bootstrap.js:54:11)

at module.exports (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi-plugin-upload/config/functions/bootstrap.js:13:36)

at execLifecycle (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:437:14)

at /srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:447:16

at Array.map (<anonymous>)

at Strapi.runLifecyclesFunctions (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:444:33)

at Strapi.load (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:379:16)

at async Strapi.start (/srv/app/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:196:9)
```

Comment: Can you try once by deleting the node modules folder, then do `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete `node_modules` and reinstall them. Strapi image installs node modules only when `node_modules` folder missing. So if you added any dependency later that dependency will not be installed automatically.